# How can I achieve $(<some-file) inside a Makefile target?

Tags: bash, makefile, jq, gnu-make

I am trying to implement the `jq` pipe `curl` command from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/lint.html#use-jq-to-create-and-process-yaml--json-payloads but inside of a make file context.

I have spent hours trying seemingly every single permutation of escaping and trying substitute commands but I can't get the equivelant to work. I have no problem outside of makefile.

I tried substituting `"$(<foo.yml)"` with `"$$(<foo.yml)"` or `$(shell cat foo.yml)` and even `cat foo.yml | ... @-` but no luck. The `shell cat` was the closest I got but cat removes \n characters which then makes the resultant JSON that I pass to GitLab come back with confusing errors:
{"valid":false,"errors":["(\u003cunknown\u003e): block sequence entries are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 12"],"warnings":[],"status":"invalid"}

I compared the string with the working original version outside of Makefile context and the only thing different is the lack of \n characters.

Please help! Thank you.

**EDIT**
As requested, here are the extra details from the URL.

This is the command I am trying to move into a Makefile context. This command works fine from directly from my bash terminal.

```sh
jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(<.gitlab-ci.yml)" '.content=$yaml' | curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/ci/lint?" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" --data @-
```

Here's the response:
`{"valid":true,"errors":[],"warnings":[],"status":"valid"}`

Here is my Makefile version:

```
.PHONY: lint
make lint:
    jq --null-input '.content="$(shell cat "$(GITLAB_CI_FILE_PATH)")"' | curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $(GITLAB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN)" --data @- "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/ci/lint"
```

Here's the response:
`{"valid":false,"errors":["(\u003cunknown\u003e): block sequence entries are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 12"],"warnings":[],"status":"invalid"}`

I know that this is because my makefile version does not contain newline characters.

Here is the input YAML file:

```yaml
include:
  - project: adamcunnington.info/MLG/common
    file: /cicd/.gitlab-ci-python.yml
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant code inline in the question.   Most readers will not follow links in questions.

Comment: Try `jq -nM --arg yaml "$$(cat foo.yml)" '.content=$$yaml'` in the recipe. `"$(…)"` is a POSIX shell command substitution which will remove a final newline if present. Did you escape both `$` chars?

Comment: @HardcoreHenry I'll edit my question to add the clarity.

Comment: @urcodebetterznow I will try that now and report back, thanks.

Comment: The conjecture about newlines seems completely wrong. Why do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: @tripleee because "once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth." - or more seriously, because there is no other difference between the string that works and the string that does not :). YAML depends on indentation so if there are no new line characters, I guess it can't parse indentation properly. Doesn't seem unlikely to me that this is the problem.

Comment: @urcodebetterznow this solved it! Interestingly, I had to do:
`jq --null-input --arg yaml "$$(cat $(GITLAB_CI_FILE_PATH))" '.content=$$yaml'`
Why does this not achieve the same thing:
`jq --null-input '.content=$$(cat $(GITLAB_CI_FILE_PATH)'`
I guess it's something to do with the stripping of quotes that --arg must do. I've tried including and excluding and can't get it to behave when I plug it directly into `content=`.

Comment: I would still really like to understand how to actually just do `$(<some-file)` inside of Makefile. I've worked around it with suggestions here but how can I read a file into stdin within Makefile context?

Comment: But it _does_ contain newlines, as you can observe if you remove the pipe to `curl`.

Comment: @tripleee nope.
`jq --null-input --arg yaml "$$(cat $(GITLAB_CI_FILE_PATH))" '.content=$$yaml' | cat` produces `{"content": "include:\n  - project: adamcunnington.info/MLG/common\n    file: /cicd/.gitlab-ci-python.yml"}`
whilst `jq --null-input --arg yaml "$(shell cat $(GITLAB_CI_FILE_PATH))" '.content=$$yaml' | cat` produces `{"content": "include:   - project: adamcunnington.info/MLG/common     file: /cicd/.gitlab-ci-python.yml"}` - same with all other variations of how the file is being cat'd there except for `$$(cat ...)`

Comment: Thanks for finally (indirectly) supplying the contents of the input file to repro with. That's not the command in your question; with adaptations to run it outside a Makefile, I ran `jq --null-input ".content=\"$(cat ".gitlab-ci.yml")\""`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. You are missing escaped dollar again - but this is my favourite solution because it's compatible with jq 1.5 and avoids me using --arg yaml which is unnecessary inside of makefile context. The only thing remaining now is to understand how to literally replicate `$(<.gitlab-ci.yml)` inside of Makefile - the workaround you've supplied works but it's not the same as reading some file into stdin.

Comment: At the Bash prompt where you would test this, you don't escape these dollar signs.

Comment: Err. The whole point of the question is to provide a working solution for Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very helpful if you provide the complete rule you're trying to write.

Using `$(<foo.yml)` can't work in a make recipe because make treats everything starting with a `$` as a make variable and expands it before running the shell.  You need to escape all `$` you want the shell to see, as `$$`.

Using `$$(<foo.yml)` will work on some systems, but not other systems: that syntax is not defined by the POSIX standard and so shells that provide POSIX features will not do anything with it.  That's enhanced syntax for the bash shell.  Make always runs `/bin/sh` by default, so if your `/bin/sh` is really bash, it might work.  If not, not.

Using `$(shell cat foo.yml)` cannot work because make's shell function removes all newlines from the output before replacing it.

Since we can't see your actual rule we can't really suggest the best alternative.  Is there some reason you can't use the simple, standard:

```
jq < foo.yml
```

?

**ETA**

As explained, your shell is bash.  Make always by default uses `/bin/sh` as a shell (imagine the portability problems if make always used whatever shell the person invoking it was using).

If you can't figure out how to rewrite your makefile recipe to use standard POSIX syntax and you instead want to use bash-specific syntax, you can tell make to use bash as its shell:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

now all the bash-specific magic will work in your recipes.  Of course your makefile will not work on systems that don't have `/bin/bash`.

Comment: I have edited my question with the clarification you've asked for. Thanks for the info so far.

Comment: as per comment stream in above answer, looks like `$$(cat foo.yaml)` fixed - I would still really like to understand how to actually accomplish `$(<foo.yaml)` in a Makefile context though.

Comment: `jq` doesn't understand YAML so you can't just pipe that on standard input without any options.

Comment: @tripleee what do you mean? this is exactly what the working solution that GitLab provides does, which works just fine at terminal. `... --arg yaml $(<.gitlab-ci.yml) 'content=$$yaml'`

Comment: I am attempting to explain why `jq < foo.yml` is not an option.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'll clarify again. At the terminal, `jq --null-input --arg yaml $(<.gitlab-ci.yml) 'content=$yaml'` works fine. It IS an option. I'm asking how to achieve that in makefile, specifically the `$(<.gitlab-ci.yml)` bit.

Comment: I think I now know that the answer to this question is because this is bash-specific syntax - so I can do it inside of Makefile if I set SHELL to /bin/bash - as per MadScientist's edit. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

A much simpler and more portable rearticulation of the `jq` part would be

```sh
jq --null-input --rawfile yaml .gitlab-ci.yml '.content=$yaml'
```

Inside a `Makefile`, obviously double the dollar sign.

A minor difference is that with `--rawfile` the final newline in the file is included, too.

The `--rawfile` option was introduced in `jq` 1.6.

Comment: I think it would need to be `'.content=$$yaml'` so the `$` character is escaped - but this doesn't work, there's no such parameter as --rawfile.

Comment: Yeah, inside a Makefile you need to escape the dollar signs.

Comment: Apologies. --rawfile is a param according to docs but not in the current version in debian apt store (1.5.1; looks like --rawfile was introduced in 1.6). Also, doesn't that expect the input to be JSON rather than YAML?

Comment: The "raw" means don't assume anything, just like the other "raw" options in `jq`.

Comment: Debian Bullseye, which is the current stable version since last month, has `jq` 1.6-2, though yes, in Buster, the newest available version from the official repo is 1.5dfsg-2+b1